# Laptop fan speeds up after 10 minutes of inactivity

Tags: laptop, fan, lenovo-laptop, cpu-usage, noise

My laptop's (Lenovo Legion Y520) fan starts running fast after 5-10 mins of inactivity out of nowhere. When I open up Task Manager, the CPU utilization seems around 25-30% and then drops to ~6% in 2-3 seconds, which is followed by the fan running slower in another 2-3 seconds. It seems like my computer is being used for a program while I am away from keyboard and I cannot detect it. Are there any solutions for that? I tried everything I can find in the internet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> When I open up Task Manager, the CPU utilization seems around 25-30%
> and then drops to ~6% in 2-3 seconds

That is normal for Windows 10 and, by itself, does not present much of a CPU load.

My fan comes on for a steady 35% plus CPU load and that, too, is normal.

Open Task Manager, let it settle for 10 seconds and then see what processes are taking a lot of CPU.

For normal browsing conditions, CPU should run <5% more than 90% of the time.

I think you will find something is running that you did not anticipate or do not know about (virus) .

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem few years ago. Unfortunately, I cannot accurately remember what exactly solved it. I will list a few things I remember , try them.

> 1. Disable programs in TaskManager/ Startup.
> 2. Changing hardware acceleration for Chrome.
> 3. Decreased paging file size.
> 4. Keeping Task Manager open all the time so that I can locate problematic processes.
> 5. Suppressed some windows process that indexes files for better searchability. (this
>    might be different now that Cortana is there)
> 6. There are also programs to monitor CPU temperature.